# How to manage cross-platform binary package with conan?

Tags: opencv, cross-platform, conan

I'm trying to develop a conan package for OpenCV pre-built binaries according to our specs. I need these to be available for Windows and Linux but am at a loss on best practices to structure the conan file.

How should I package both binaries? Should I instead create a package for each OS?

Answer (score 1):

Packing OpenCV is not an easy task, there is an official recipe available and provided by Conan Community [here](https://github.com/conan-community/conan-opencv)

To install OpenCV:

```
conan install -r conan-center opencv/4.1.0@conan/stable
```

There are more versions available, you can list those version by:

```
conan search -r conan-center opencv
```

Also, there is a good blog post about OpenCV + Conan [here](https://blog.conan.io/2019/02/11/OpenCV-conan-packages.html)

> How should I package both binaries? Should I instead create a package for each OS?

Each recipe should be able to distribute the same project for ANY platform. You can create multiple methods, one per OS. For example, some projects are distributed with CMake and autotools, where CMake only works on Windows. Take a look in OpenCV Conan recipe, you can learn a lot.

If you are interested in packages where you need to download an installer, so [mingw](https://github.com/conan-community/conan-mingw-installer/blob/master/conanfile.py) Conan recipe is a good example.

Regards!